# Restful api using unirest

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, httprequest

i'm trying to get data using restful api, but i get an error even though i've followed the install guide. my code look like this from mashape:

```
NSDictionary* headers = @{@"X-Mashape-Authorization": @"key"};
NSDictionary* parameters = @{};

HttpJsonResponse* response = [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest* request) {
    [request setUrl:@"https://willjw-statsfc-competitions.p.mashape.com/live.json?key=free&competition=premier-league&team=everton&group=A&timezone=Europe%2FLondon"];

    [request setHeaders:headers];
    [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJson];
```

I get the error:

```
User of undeclared identifier HttpJsonResponse
Use of undeclared identifier response
```

I've uploaded all the unirest files and imported UNIrest.h into the ViewController

Comment: What does *"it seems like i get an error"* mean?

Comment: It means that english is not my first language and that i have two errors listed at the bottom.

Comment: check whether the library files (HttpJsonResponse) are imported correctly in the compile sources files panel in your Xcode project.